# Как сделать рисование SVG линии при скроле

Tags: jquery, svg

Как на основе [этого](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/path.html) примера нарисовать эти линии?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вообще как подготовить такой path для дальнейшего использование для анимаций

Comment: в примере в зависимости от положения прокрутки устанавливается `stroke-dashoffset` у линии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/svg_drawing.html хорошая библиотека, в примере используется https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr
На русском материалов почти нет, можете тут посмотреть [ScrollMagic – Создание анимации при прокрутке страницы](http://www.creative-seo.ru/blog/scrollmagic-sozdanie-animacii-pri-prokrutke-stranicy/)